# what's the equivalent of this curl request in swift

Tags: ios, swift, http, post, curl

I've tried lots of different things to recreate this curl request, and I'm going insane.  If someone could help, I'd be very much appreciative.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '[{"a": 4, "b": 5, "c": 6}]' \ -u username:password \ https://www.mywebsite.com
```

My latest attempt is:

```
    let loginString = NSString(format: "%@:%@", username!, password!)
    let loginData: NSData = loginString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(nil)

    var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: "www.mywebsite.com")!

    var request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.setValue("Basic \(base64LoginString)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.addValue("text/plain; charset=UTF-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    let bodyData = JSON(data!).rawString(encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.allZeros)
    request.HTTPBody = bodyData?.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {(response, data, error) in
        if let tabBarVC : TabBarController = self.tabBarController as? TabBarController {
            println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
        }
    }
```

In this example, data is a dictionary ([String:String]) and JSON is form SwiftyJSON.

The above sends NSData to the server, which is encoded and the server doesn't like.  The request is getting through, but the server can't read the data right.  What do I need to do to exactly replicate the curl request above?  I'm stuck!

Updated to reflect good responses below.

I did attempt to use application/json for content-type, but this returns the message:

```
{"status": "Internal error JSON uploads must be formatted as an array of objects", "code": 400, "version": "v1"}
```

It seems like progress if I use text/plain (as above) I get:

```
{"status": "Column a is missing", "code": 400, "version": "v1"}
```

Which I can't seem to figure out.

Comment: I recommend you to check out [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking), it will make your requests a whole lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

1. If nothing else, the line that says:

   ```
   request.addValue("text/plain; charset=UTF-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
   ```

   Should be:

   ```
   request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
   ```

   Your `curl` clearly states that the content type header was supposed to be JSON, so I'd set that accordingly.
2. Also, the line that says:

   ```
   request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept-encoding")
   ```

   That's clearly not correct, either. I think you meant `Accept` not `Accept-encoding`, plus the server is undoubtedly not responding with a `x-www-form-urlencoded` response, anyway.

   I would simply remove that line.
3. Your URL is missing the scheme (the `http://`), but I assume that was removed when editing your question, because I don't think it would work without that, but you assured us that the server did receive the request.
4. I'd suggest you consider a tool like [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com). Watch the request from `curl` and then again from your code. Compare and contrast and identify how they differ. Using this, you should be able to diagnose precisely what's going on and where the discrepancy rests.
5. You say:

   > The request is getting through, but the server can't read the data right.

   If the problem persists, you should share with us how you know the request is getting through and what you mean by "can't read the data right."

Comment: This is really helpful... I added some detail above to help explain what I mean by "request getting through"...

Comment: Yep, that's great. That would suggest that your connection was established properly, but that the JSON wasn't right. You don't share how you built `data`, so I cannot comment on that further. If you used Charles and looked at the request, you'd undoubtedly see what the problem was, though.

Comment: the results from Charles is just a big pile of garbled encoded text... not particularly helpful.

as far as the structure of data, it's a dictionary [String:String]...

Comment: The goal of the Charles exercise was to compare the `curl` request to the code request. Did all the headers match? Was it only the body of the request that was garbled, but everything else was fine? If so, that tells you that your code to build `bodyData` is flawed, doesn't it? Have you examined the `bodyData` that you used when building the request (converting it back to a `NSString` first, of course)? What does that look like? The goal of the exercise was to identify what precisely was wrong, and then go back and confirm that portion of the original request.